# How to create a module?

Tags: python, import, module

I'm trying to create a module foo that I can import and call functions from using `foo.getNum()` etc. I was able to get it to work using:

```
from foo import numbers
```

where `numbers` is a class defined in the `numbers.py` file with a `def getNum()`.

In a directory named `foo`, I have an `__init__.py` that contains:

```
from numbers import numbers
```

Then from one directory up, in my test script it imports `foo` using:

```
from foo import numbers
```

I would like to be able to just use:

```
import foo

foo.getNum()
```

instead of:

```
from foo import numbers

mynumbers = numbers()
mynumbers.getNum()
```

Comment: You're trying to get the method of a class directly into the namespace without instantiating the class.  Not to be rude, but this doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  If you just wanted to reference the class itself, put `from numbers import *` in your `__init__.py` file and consider specifying `__all__` in `number`.

Comment: Thanks to Brad. It made more sense to take away the class, and in the init have from numbers import *